# Safari can’t find the server `localhost` for a one specific directory

Tags: macos, apache, safari, mamp

When I open one of my project CMS Safari says

> safari cannot open the page "localhost:8888/mamp because safari cannot
>   find the server localhost.

However when I open another project, html website, php website etc - everything is fine...

I had a problem with mod_rewrite and .htaccess cos there was 404 but following advice I changed http.conf line > AllowOverride All

And now I see just info - Safari cannot open the page "localhost:8888/mamp because safari cannot find the server localhost.

I can't find solution

.htaccess ( first two pages )

[1st page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH0tz.jpg) 
[2nd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw16M.jpg)

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8888/mamp` works?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8888 works and show me htdocs directory

127.0.0.1:8888/mamp - doesn't work - 404...

Comment: Does your mamp folder has a index file? If not,could you share your htaccess with us

Comment: Yes id does. I added the picture of my htaccess in my post.